# Is a matrix $A$ computable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring which is not necessarily a UFD.
For $3\times3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ whose entries are in $R$, $A$ is upper triangular, $B$ is invertible, and $BAB^{-1}$ is given.

Then is it possible to compute $A$?

I think if $R$ is a UFD, then $A$ can be computed by using Jordan canonical form but I'm not so sure. Any suggestion or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Using $\mathbb{R}$ in this context is confusing.

Comment: Are you asking whether A is uniquely determined, or whether at least one such matrix A exists?

Comment: $BAB^{-1}$ is given, so let this matrix be $C.$  I.e. $C=BAB^{-1}$. Multiply on the right by $B$ on both sides of the equation. Then $CB=BA$. Multiply on the left by $B^{-1}$ on both sides of the equation.  Then $B^{-1}CB=A$.  Either this is the answer, or I've completely missed the point of this question.

Comment: I don't know B. we only know BAB^-1

Comment: Okay, so if I'm understanding this correctly, you're given a matrix $C.$ You know it can be written in the form $BAB^{-1}$ where $A$ is upper triangular, but you don't know what $A$ and $B$ are.  So you want to find $A$ (and $B$ along with it, I suppose) given $C$.  All of the ways I know of doing this assume $R$ is a field (for example, the Jordan canonical form and the Schur decomposition). I'm not sure what can be done if $R$ is not a field.  It's an intriguing problem!

Comment: BTW, one book that might give you some insight, if you can get your hands on it, is Morris Newman's *Integral Matrices*. It discusses canonical forms and the like for matrices whose entries may or may not come from a field.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ is not uniquely identified by $BAB^{-1}$ and the fact that $A$ is upper triangular.  If $B$ is upper triangular then $BAB^{-1}$ is as well and certainly needn't equal $A$, so there are multiple possible values for $A$.

Also note that Jordan canonical forms aren't unique.  If it has more than one Jordan block then these blocks can be permuted.

Comment: thank you. I'll think about it